# Convert string to int in xcode

Tags: xcode4.5

I have two text fields.I need to convert text values into int. So i can add two values and display in result text field.Somebody please help me to convert string to integer.

Answer (score 5):

You don't specify whether you're using iOS or OSX, which doesn't help answer the question.

Regardless, if you're using OSX, then `NSTextField` derives from `NSControl` which provides an `intValue` method:

```
int number = [myTextField intValue];
```

([reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSControl/intValue)).

And if you're using iOS then `UITextField` provides its value via the `text` property (`NSString`) which provides an `intValue` method:

```
int number = [[myTextField text] intValue];
```

([reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/intValue)).

There are variations of these methods which also provide their value as `float`, `double`, etc.

Comment: I am using osx lion 10.7.5.
no visible @interface for UItextvalue declares the selector inValue.what is meaning of this error?.

Comment: @user1799283 You mean `NSTextField` don't you.

Comment: i am adding two textfield values on add button action.

Comment: @user1799283 OK when you say "osx lion 10.7.5" you mean you are developing under Lion for iOS.  These details are important.  The class is called `UITextField`, not `UItextvalue` or `UItextfield` (case is important).

Answer (score 0):

```
int *vla = (int)[string number here];
```